# Error serializing Avro message

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Kafka Streams with Spring Boot in my project. In my use case, I send an Order object by serializing with `SpecificAvroSerializer` and consuming with KStream API. When I send the object with KafkaProducer I get following exception

`nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message] with root cause. java.lang.NullPointerException: null`

Developed this project based on [Confluent examples](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/kafka-0.10.0.x-cp-3.0.1/kafka-streams/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/utils). Not sure where I made a mistake. I would really appreciate any help. Code uploaded to [Github](https://github.com/pavankjadda/KafkaStream-CQRS-EventSourcing) for reference.

Exception:

```
   2018-04-17 16:19:39.170 ERROR 6161 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:57) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:89) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:72) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:54) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.kafkastream.stream.SpecificAvroSerializer.serialize(SpecificAvroSerializer.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.kafkastream.stream.SpecificAvroSerializer.serialize(SpecificAvroSerializer.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:65) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:55) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:791) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:768) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:656) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.kafkastream.service.EventsSender.sendCustomerEvent(EventsSender.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.kafkastream.web.EventsController.sendCustomers(EventsController.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

Comment: Which serializer/Deserialize you are using?

Comment: SpecificAvroSerializer. It’s part of the Confluent platform

Comment: Interesting, we are using confluent too but not with Kstream and we are using below deserializers             `value.deserializer="io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer"`
            `key.deserializer="io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer"`

Comment: @explorer: Are you using this with Kafka Producer?

Comment: @Explorer Can you share the piece of code if possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I am able to fix this issue. I did one basic mistake with Avro serde. Model classes are automatically generated by avro tools based on Customer.avsc or Order.avsc files. I was creating these classes manually and implementing Specific Record class with them. After implementation, Overriden methods i.e getSchema(), get, put did not have any code. When compiler executed `getSchema()` statement, it returned `null` and threw `Null Pointer Exception`.

```
package com.kafkastream.model;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Customer implements SpecificRecord
{
    public String   customerId;

    public String   firstName;

    public String   lastName;

    public String   email;

    public String   phone;


    public Customer()
    {

    }
    public Customer(String customerId, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String phone)
    {
        this.customerId = customerId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    // Getters and Setters here


    @Override
    public void put(int i, Object o)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public Object get(int i)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Schema getSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

After some research I made few changes to the project.

1. Added `avro-tools` dependency to the project
2. Added avro generator plugin to pom.xml file

**Plugin**:

```
               <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${avro.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                            <goal>protocol</goal>
                            <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

3. Created Customer.avsc, Order.avsc and Greetings.avsc files under ../resources/avro folder
4. Compiled the project after this `mvn clean package --DskipTests` or `Right click on project Maven --> Generate sources`

Compiling project automatically creates model classes in model folder (Customer class shown below) by avro tools

**Customer.java (Generated by avro)**

```
/**
 * Autogenerated by Avro
 *
 * DO NOT EDIT DIRECTLY
 */
package com.kafkastream.model;

import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData;
import org.apache.avro.message.BinaryMessageEncoder;
import org.apache.avro.message.BinaryMessageDecoder;
import org.apache.avro.message.SchemaStore;

@SuppressWarnings("all")
@org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated
public class Customer extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2729048783015827572L;
  public static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Customer\",\"namespace\":\"com.kafkastream.model\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"customerId\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"firstName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"lastName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"email\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"phone\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}");
  public static org.apache.avro.Schema getClassSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }

  private static SpecificData MODEL$ = new SpecificData();

  private static final BinaryMessageEncoder<Customer> ENCODER =
      new BinaryMessageEncoder<Customer>(MODEL$, SCHEMA$);

  private static final BinaryMessageDecoder<Customer> DECODER =
      new BinaryMessageDecoder<Customer>(MODEL$, SCHEMA$);

  /**
   * Return the BinaryMessageDecoder instance used by this class.
   */
  public static BinaryMessageDecoder<Customer> getDecoder() {
    return DECODER;
  }

  /**
   * Create a new BinaryMessageDecoder instance for this class that uses the specified {@link SchemaStore}.
   * @param resolver a {@link SchemaStore} used to find schemas by fingerprint
   */
  public static BinaryMessageDecoder<Customer> createDecoder(SchemaStore resolver) {
    return new BinaryMessageDecoder<Customer>(MODEL$, SCHEMA$, resolver);
  }

  /** Serializes this Customer to a ByteBuffer. */
  public java.nio.ByteBuffer toByteBuffer() throws java.io.IOException {
    return ENCODER.encode(this);
  }

  /** Deserializes a Customer from a ByteBuffer. */
  public static Customer fromByteBuffer(
      java.nio.ByteBuffer b) throws java.io.IOException {
    return DECODER.decode(b);
  }

  @Deprecated public java.lang.CharSequence customerId;
  @Deprecated public java.lang.CharSequence firstName;
  @Deprecated public java.lang.CharSequence lastName;
  @Deprecated public java.lang.CharSequence email;
  @Deprecated public java.lang.CharSequence phone;

  /**
   * Default constructor.  Note that this does not initialize fields
   * to their default values from the schema.  If that is desired then
   * one should use <code>newBuilder()</code>.
   */
  public Customer() {}

  /**
   * All-args constructor.
   * @param customerId The new value for customerId
   * @param firstName The new value for firstName
   * @param lastName The new value for lastName
   * @param email The new value for email
   * @param phone The new value for phone
   */
  public Customer(java.lang.CharSequence customerId, java.lang.CharSequence firstName, java.lang.CharSequence lastName, java.lang.CharSequence email, java.lang.CharSequence phone) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
  }

  public org.apache.avro.Schema getSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }
  // Used by DatumWriter.  Applications should not call.
  public java.lang.Object get(int field$) {
    switch (field$) {
    case 0: return customerId;
    case 1: return firstName;
    case 2: return lastName;
    case 3: return email;
    case 4: return phone;
    default: throw new org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException("Bad index");
    }
  }

  // Used by DatumReader.  Applications should not call.
  @SuppressWarnings(value="unchecked")
  public void put(int field$, java.lang.Object value$) {
    switch (field$) {
    case 0: customerId = (java.lang.CharSequence)value$; break;
    case 1: firstName = (java.lang.CharSequence)value$; break;
    case 2: lastName = (java.lang.CharSequence)value$; break;
    case 3: email = (java.lang.CharSequence)value$; break;
    case 4: phone = (java.lang.CharSequence)value$; break;
    default: throw new org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException("Bad index");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Gets the value of the 'customerId' field.
   * @return The value of the 'customerId' field.
   */
  public java.lang.CharSequence getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the value of the 'customerId' field.
   * @param value the value to set.
   */
  public void setCustomerId(java.lang.CharSequence value) {
    this.customerId = value;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the value of the 'firstName' field.
   * @return The value of the 'firstName' field.
   */
  public java.lang.CharSequence getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the value of the 'firstName' field.
   * @param value the value to set.
   */
  public void setFirstName(java.lang.CharSequence value) {
    this.firstName = value;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the value of the 'lastName' field.
   * @return The value of the 'lastName' field.
   */
  public java.lang.CharSequence getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the value of the 'lastName' field.
   * @param value the value to set.
   */
  public void setLastName(java.lang.CharSequence value) {
    this.lastName = value;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the value of the 'email' field.
   * @return The value of the 'email' field.
   */
  public java.lang.CharSequence getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the value of the 'email' field.
   * @param value the value to set.
   */
  public void setEmail(java.lang.CharSequence value) {
    this.email = value;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the value of the 'phone' field.
   * @return The value of the 'phone' field.
   */
  public java.lang.CharSequence getPhone() {
    return phone;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the value of the 'phone' field.
   * @param value the value to set.
   */
  public void setPhone(java.lang.CharSequence value) {
    this.phone = value;
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new Customer RecordBuilder.
   * @return A new Customer RecordBuilder
   */
  public static com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder newBuilder() {
    return new com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder();
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new Customer RecordBuilder by copying an existing Builder.
   * @param other The existing builder to copy.
   * @return A new Customer RecordBuilder
   */
  public static com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder newBuilder(com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder other) {
    return new com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder(other);
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new Customer RecordBuilder by copying an existing Customer instance.
   * @param other The existing instance to copy.
   * @return A new Customer RecordBuilder
   */
  public static com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder newBuilder(com.kafkastream.model.Customer other) {
    return new com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder(other);
  }

  /**
   * RecordBuilder for Customer instances.
   */
  public static class Builder extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBuilderBase<Customer>
    implements org.apache.avro.data.RecordBuilder<Customer> {

    private java.lang.CharSequence customerId;
    private java.lang.CharSequence firstName;
    private java.lang.CharSequence lastName;
    private java.lang.CharSequence email;
    private java.lang.CharSequence phone;

    /** Creates a new Builder */
    private Builder() {
      super(SCHEMA$);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Builder by copying an existing Builder.
     * @param other The existing Builder to copy.
     */
    private Builder(com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder other) {
      super(other);
      if (isValidValue(fields()[0], other.customerId)) {
        this.customerId = data().deepCopy(fields()[0].schema(), other.customerId);
        fieldSetFlags()[0] = true;
      }
      if (isValidValue(fields()[1], other.firstName)) {
        this.firstName = data().deepCopy(fields()[1].schema(), other.firstName);
        fieldSetFlags()[1] = true;
      }
      if (isValidValue(fields()[2], other.lastName)) {
        this.lastName = data().deepCopy(fields()[2].schema(), other.lastName);
        fieldSetFlags()[2] = true;
      }
      if (isValidValue(fields()[3], other.email)) {
        this.email = data().deepCopy(fields()[3].schema(), other.email);
        fieldSetFlags()[3] = true;
      }
      if (isValidValue(fields()[4], other.phone)) {
        this.phone = data().deepCopy(fields()[4].schema(), other.phone);
        fieldSetFlags()[4] = true;
      }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Builder by copying an existing Customer instance
     * @param other The existing instance to copy.
     */
    private Builder(com.kafkastream.model.Customer other) {
            super(SCHEMA$);
      if (isValidValue(fields()[0], other.customerId)) {
        this.customerId = data().deepCopy(fields()[0].schema(), other.customerId);
        fieldSetFlags()[0] = true;
      }
      if (isValidValue(fields()[1], other.firstName)) {
        this.firstName = data().deepCopy(fields()[1].schema(), other.firstName);
        fieldSetFlags()[1] = true;
      }
      if (isValidValue(fields()[2], other.lastName)) {
        this.lastName = data().deepCopy(fields()[2].schema(), other.lastName);
        fieldSetFlags()[2] = true;
      }
      if (isValidValue(fields()[3], other.email)) {
        this.email = data().deepCopy(fields()[3].schema(), other.email);
        fieldSetFlags()[3] = true;
      }
      if (isValidValue(fields()[4], other.phone)) {
        this.phone = data().deepCopy(fields()[4].schema(), other.phone);
        fieldSetFlags()[4] = true;
      }
    }

    /**
      * Gets the value of the 'customerId' field.
      * @return The value.
      */
    public java.lang.CharSequence getCustomerId() {
      return customerId;
    }

    /**
      * Sets the value of the 'customerId' field.
      * @param value The value of 'customerId'.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder setCustomerId(java.lang.CharSequence value) {
      validate(fields()[0], value);
      this.customerId = value;
      fieldSetFlags()[0] = true;
      return this;
    }

    /**
      * Checks whether the 'customerId' field has been set.
      * @return True if the 'customerId' field has been set, false otherwise.
      */
    public boolean hasCustomerId() {
      return fieldSetFlags()[0];
    }


    /**
      * Clears the value of the 'customerId' field.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder clearCustomerId() {
      customerId = null;
      fieldSetFlags()[0] = false;
      return this;
    }

    /**
      * Gets the value of the 'firstName' field.
      * @return The value.
      */
    public java.lang.CharSequence getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
    }

    /**
      * Sets the value of the 'firstName' field.
      * @param value The value of 'firstName'.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder setFirstName(java.lang.CharSequence value) {
      validate(fields()[1], value);
      this.firstName = value;
      fieldSetFlags()[1] = true;
      return this;
    }

    /**
      * Checks whether the 'firstName' field has been set.
      * @return True if the 'firstName' field has been set, false otherwise.
      */
    public boolean hasFirstName() {
      return fieldSetFlags()[1];
    }


    /**
      * Clears the value of the 'firstName' field.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder clearFirstName() {
      firstName = null;
      fieldSetFlags()[1] = false;
      return this;
    }

    /**
      * Gets the value of the 'lastName' field.
      * @return The value.
      */
    public java.lang.CharSequence getLastName() {
      return lastName;
    }

    /**
      * Sets the value of the 'lastName' field.
      * @param value The value of 'lastName'.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder setLastName(java.lang.CharSequence value) {
      validate(fields()[2], value);
      this.lastName = value;
      fieldSetFlags()[2] = true;
      return this;
    }

    /**
      * Checks whether the 'lastName' field has been set.
      * @return True if the 'lastName' field has been set, false otherwise.
      */
    public boolean hasLastName() {
      return fieldSetFlags()[2];
    }


    /**
      * Clears the value of the 'lastName' field.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder clearLastName() {
      lastName = null;
      fieldSetFlags()[2] = false;
      return this;
    }

    /**
      * Gets the value of the 'email' field.
      * @return The value.
      */
    public java.lang.CharSequence getEmail() {
      return email;
    }

    /**
      * Sets the value of the 'email' field.
      * @param value The value of 'email'.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder setEmail(java.lang.CharSequence value) {
      validate(fields()[3], value);
      this.email = value;
      fieldSetFlags()[3] = true;
      return this;
    }

    /**
      * Checks whether the 'email' field has been set.
      * @return True if the 'email' field has been set, false otherwise.
      */
    public boolean hasEmail() {
      return fieldSetFlags()[3];
    }


    /**
      * Clears the value of the 'email' field.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder clearEmail() {
      email = null;
      fieldSetFlags()[3] = false;
      return this;
    }

    /**
      * Gets the value of the 'phone' field.
      * @return The value.
      */
    public java.lang.CharSequence getPhone() {
      return phone;
    }

    /**
      * Sets the value of the 'phone' field.
      * @param value The value of 'phone'.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder setPhone(java.lang.CharSequence value) {
      validate(fields()[4], value);
      this.phone = value;
      fieldSetFlags()[4] = true;
      return this;
    }

    /**
      * Checks whether the 'phone' field has been set.
      * @return True if the 'phone' field has been set, false otherwise.
      */
    public boolean hasPhone() {
      return fieldSetFlags()[4];
    }


    /**
      * Clears the value of the 'phone' field.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public com.kafkastream.model.Customer.Builder clearPhone() {
      phone = null;
      fieldSetFlags()[4] = false;
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Customer build() {
      try {
        Customer record = new Customer();
        record.customerId = fieldSetFlags()[0] ? this.customerId : (java.lang.CharSequence) defaultValue(fields()[0]);
        record.firstName = fieldSetFlags()[1] ? this.firstName : (java.lang.CharSequence) defaultValue(fields()[1]);
        record.lastName = fieldSetFlags()[2] ? this.lastName : (java.lang.CharSequence) defaultValue(fields()[2]);
        record.email = fieldSetFlags()[3] ? this.email : (java.lang.CharSequence) defaultValue(fields()[3]);
        record.phone = fieldSetFlags()[4] ? this.phone : (java.lang.CharSequence) defaultValue(fields()[4]);
        return record;
      } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        throw new org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private static final org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter<Customer>
    WRITER$ = (org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter<Customer>)MODEL$.createDatumWriter(SCHEMA$);

  @Override public void writeExternal(java.io.ObjectOutput out)
    throws java.io.IOException {
    WRITER$.write(this, SpecificData.getEncoder(out));
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private static final org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader<Customer>
    READER$ = (org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader<Customer>)MODEL$.createDatumReader(SCHEMA$);

  @Override public void readExternal(java.io.ObjectInput in)
    throws java.io.IOException {
    READER$.read(this, SpecificData.getDecoder(in));
  }

}
```

I hope this post helps someone.